# Convert Byte Array to FileStream

Tags: arrays, powershell, filestream

I need help to convert Byte Array to File Stream. I am using following powershell script to download document from web

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$bytearr = $wc.downloaddata('URL')
```

Now, I need to pass this Byte Array to FileSteam

```
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = ## Need to Pass Byte Array as FileStream ##
```

Any help?

Comment: `[IO.MemoryStream]$bytearr` ?

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm 
How much naive of me :(

Comment: Exactly @wOxxOm 
I am looking for powershell examples

Comment: @ wOxxOm Please add the answer.

Comment: @wOxxOm I second JPBlanc - please, add as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Sharepoint API, but looking at the documentation for the [`FileCreationInformation` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filecreationinformation.aspx) I see there is a [`Content` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filecreationinformation.content.aspx) of type `byte[]`.  Assuming it serves the same purpose as the [`ContentStream` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filecreationinformation.contentstream.aspx), you could do simply...

```
$FileCreationInfo.Content = $bytearr
```

If you don't need the data at `'URL'` for anything other than populating `$FileCreationInfo`, consider calling the [`WebClient.OpenRead` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/781fwaz8.aspx) instead to get the data as a `Stream` in the first place...

```
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $wc.OpenRead('URI')
```

As a last resort, and to answer the general question, you can "convert" a `byte[]` to a `Stream` by wrapping it in a [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx)...

```
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = New-Object -TypeName 'System.IO.MemoryStream' -ArgumentList (,$bytearr)
```

I have omitted this from my code snippets, but don't forget to [`Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx)/[`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms227422.aspx) any `Stream` objects you create if the SharePoint client doesn't handle that for you!